# How to get a string of union set from a vector string?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have a vector string filled with some file extensions as follows:

```
vector<string> vExt;
vExt.push_back("*.JPG;*.TGA;*.TIF");
vExt.push_back("*.PNG;*.RAW");
vExt.push_back("*.BMP;*.HDF");
vExt.push_back("*.GIF");
vExt.push_back("*.JPG");
vExt.push_back("*.BMP");
```

I now want to get a string of union set from the above-mentioned vector string, in which each file extension must be unique in the resulting string. As for my given example, the resulting string should take the form of `"*.JPG;*.TGA;*.TIF;*.PNG;*.RAW;*.BMP;*.HDF;*.GIF"`.

I know that std::unique can remove consecutive duplicates in range. It con't work with my condition. Would you please show me how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: does the sort order of the resulting output matter?

Comment: @Foo Bah: I don't care about the order of the element in the resulting string. How to use non-boost version of tokenizing to do my job? Thank you.

Comment: @sehe: Nobody want to be a masochist. I want to use the resulting string as an include filter of my directory watching routine. So, no duplicate is allowed.

Comment: @GoldenLee: I was referring to the habitual "would you like fries with that" type of questioning in the comments. It turns out I hadn't read the sample data too well. _Fixed my answer_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See it live here: http://ideone.com/0fmy0 (**FIXED**)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vExt;
    vExt.push_back("*.JPG;*.TGA;*.TIF");
    vExt.push_back("*.PNG;*.RAW");
    vExt.push_back("*.BMP;*.HDF");
    vExt.push_back("*.GIF");
    vExt.push_back("*.JPG");
    vExt.push_back("*.BMP");

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::copy(vExt.begin(), vExt.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss, ";"));

    std::string element;
    std::set<std::string> unique;
    while (std::getline(ss, element, ';'))
        unique.insert(unique.end(), element);

    std::stringstream oss;

    std::copy(unique.begin(), unique.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(oss, ";"));

    std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
*.BMP;*.GIF;*.HDF;*.JPG;*.PNG;*.RAW;*.TGA;*.TIF;
```

Comment: @MSalters: oops, read too quickly (didn't read the data). Fixed now

Comment: @sehe: Thank you very much! I have a test of your "short and clear" program. It just concatenate all element string together to form a big string. It also include the duplicate file extension such as *.JPG, and *.BMP.

Comment: @GoldenLee: thanks for confirming, I guess :) It didn't just do _that_, but I agree for the test data given, the net effect was the same. My bad. See fixed version?

Answer (score 1):

I'd [tokenize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) each string into constituent parts (using semicolon as the separator), and stick the resulting tokens into a set. The resultant contents of that set is what you're looking for.

Comment: the non-boost version of tokenizing takes 3 lines and avoids having to use the boost libraries

Comment: @aix: Thank you for your quick response. Is there a way to do that without using boost library? I really don't want to use the BOOST library to finish this kind of simpel job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the strings that contain multiple file extensions and then push them into the vector. After that `std::unique` will do what you want. Have a look at the Boost.Tokenizer class, that should make this trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I know, std::unique can remove consecutive duplicates in range, for example:
int myints[] = {10,20,20,20,30,30,20,20,10};    // 10 20 20 20 30 30 20 20 10
vector<int> myvector (myints,myints+9);
vector<int>::iterator it;
// using default comparison:
it = unique (myvector.begin(), myvector.end()); // 10 20 30 20 10 ?  ?  ?  ?
myvector.resize( it - myvector.begin() );       // 10 20 30 20 10

Comment: You'd need to sort the vector, else the duplicates won't be adjacent. Of course, you'd need to use consistent predicates for std::sort and std::unique. If ".jpg" is a duplicate of ".JPG", they should sort together.